# share-like button

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, button

I'm trying to create a button that people will be able to add to their websites, just like twitter or facebook buttons. I want that button to generate an iframe on the page that overlays the content of the page. Is it possible to do something like that? are there any examples on the web of similar scripts?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this?

```
var iframe = $("<iframe src='something' />");
$("#likeButtonPlaceholder").append(iframe);
```